# How does one read AxB as in "A by B grid" in Japanese?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics

Here's the definition of sudoku in Wikipedia:

数独（すうどく）とは、3×3のブロックに区切られた 9×9の正方形の枠内に1〜9までの数字を入れるペンシルパズルの一つである。

How should one read 9×9の or 3×3の out loud?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're asking this because in English, we distinguish *times* from *by*:

- 3**×**3=9　　　　 　 　  three *times* three is nine
- a 3**×**3 block　　 　 　a three-*by*-three block

But I think in Japanese, it's just かける in both cases:

- ３**×**３＝９　　　　　さん**かける**さんはきゅう
- ３**×**３のブロック　　さん**かける**さんのブロック

You can see that both uses are listed on [Wikipedia's article for `×`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%97#.E7.A9.8D) in the same section (titled 積), and in that section it says that the symbol is usually pronounced かける.

This [ALC example](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=will+four+by+six) also uses かける to correspond to English *by*, although this example has units:

> Also about the photo size, would you like it **four by six inches** or **three by five inches**?
>
> あと、写真の大きさですが、**4インチかける6インチ**のと**3インチかける5インチ**がありますが、どちらにしますか？

I also found some videos online where `×` was used to express dimensions, and they pronounced it かける in each case.  For example, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__pwVMiD6hA) and [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSOLGqb81v4) say 2×2 and 3×3 as に**かける**に and さん**かける**さん.  (They're both Minecraft videos.)

So I think you can just say "*number* かける *number*".